# BeautifoulSoup Extract text from img tag - Python

Tags: python, html, image, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I was wondering how to extract text that's stored after an img tag in html.
The hmtl looks like this:

```
<img style="vertical-align:-3px" src="/images/icons/flag_green.png"> == $0 " 17.12.2020"
```

I'd like to extract the date " 17.12.2020"

What I tried so far:

```
Date = pageSoup.find_all("img", {"style": "vertical-align:-3px"})
```

What I get out is all the content besides the desired date.

```
Date[0].text
```

doesn't work here....

Hope someone can hep me out here. Thank you very much guys

Comment: no you cannot. Image doesn't contain anything in it. provide the parent element. Then I can give you another alternative path by which you can extract. from img you cannot.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I got it from the parent element. Didn't know that I have to get it from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with regex.
Assuming the date is always in the format: [DD].[MM].[YYYY]:

```
import re 
re.search("([0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{4})", Object)
```

where "Object" is where the hmtl string  is stored.

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting the HTML on the quotes `"`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<img style="vertical-align:-3px" src="/images/icons/flag_green.png"> == $0 " 17.12.2020"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

>>> print(soup.find("img").next.split('"')[-1])
 17.12.2020
```